# Why do we need absolute continuity of $\langle M \rangle_t(\omega)$ with repect to the Lebesgue measure?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, absolute-continuity

I am trying to understand the proof of proposition 3.2.6 in Stochastic Calculus and Brownian Motion by Karatzas and Shreve. For $X$ bounded they use Lemma 3.2.4 in the same book and eventually claim(the arguments are detailed below) that $[X^{(m_k)}-X] \to 0$ using the bounded convergence theorem and the **absolute continuity of $ t \mapsto\langle M \rangle_t$**

**I do not understand why do we need the  almost sure absolute continuity of the quadratic variation of $M$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure in the proof**

**Proposition 3.2.6**
If the function $t \mapsto \langle M \rangle_t(\omega)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure for $P-$a.e $\omega \in \Omega$, then $\mathcal{L}_0$ isn dense in $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to the metric
$$
d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\left(1 \wedge [x-y]_n\right)
$$ where
$$
[X]_n^2=E\int_0^n X_u^2 d\langle M \rangle_u
$$
Proof

If $X \in \mathcal{L}$ is bounded ,then Lemma 3.2.4 guarantees the existence of a bounded sequence $\{X^{(m)}\}$ of simple processes satisfying
 $$
 \sup_{T>0} \lim_{m \to \infty} E \int_0^T \vert X_t^{(m)}-X_t \vert^2 dt =0
 $$
That is $X^{(m)}$ converges to $X$ in $L^2$ and therefore in probability and hence from it we can extract a subsequence $\{X^{(m_k)}\}$ such that the set
 $$
 \{(t, \omega) \in [0,\infty) \times  \Omega: \lim_{k \to \infty} X^{(m_k)}_t(\omega)=X_t(\omega)\}^c
 $$
 has product measure zero.

Now looking at $d(X^{(m_k)}, X)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\left(1 \wedge [X^{(m_k)}- X]_n\right)$ and in particular on the sequence below for a fixed $n$
$$
[X^{(m_k)}- X]_n=E\int_0^n (X^{(m_k)}- X)^2 d\langle M \rangle_u
$$
and then taking the limits as $k \to \infty$ and recalling that $X$ is assumed to be bounded and by construction(in Lemma 3.2.4 of the same book)  the sequence $X^{(m_k)}$ is uniformly bounded by the same constant, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that

$ \lim_{k \to \infty}[X^{(m_k)}- X]_n =\lim_{k \to \infty} E\int_0^n (X^{(m_k)}- X)^2 d\langle M \rangle_u =E\int_0^n \lim_{k \to \infty} (X^{(m_k)}- X)^2 d\langle M \rangle_u=0$
**Where is the absolute continuity being used here? Since the quadratic variation is an increasing right continuous process, it induces a measure, where does the absolute continuity come into play?**

Comment: The answer isn't in the proof (you are right) but in the motivation.properly explained by the authors at the begininng of the chapter at page 131 in my edition : "[...]If the function $t ,ω\to <M>_t,(ω)$ is absolutely continuous for P-a.e. ω, we shall be able to construct $\int_0^t X_s dM_s$, for all $\forall X \in \mathcal {L}$  and all Τ > 0. In the absence of this condition on $<M>$, we shall construct the stochastic integral for X in the slightly smaller class $\mathcal {L}^*$.[...]" regards

Comment: Dominated convergence requires that the sequence converge to the limit a.e. And $X^{(m_k)}$ satisfies this condition with respect to $\text{Lebesgue}\times P$ (first part of the proof).

Comment: @TheBridge what I still don’t get is, since the authors mention that for absolutely continuous quadratic variation we can construct the stochastic integral for a larger class of integrands , but I don’t understand why is the absolute continuity essential in this construction of the stochastic integral . So in summary I do not follow how what the author says in the introduction explains the technical requirement of absolute continuity in Proposition 3.2.6 in Shreve

Comment: Again, if $\langle M\rangle$ is not absolutely continuous, you can't use dominated convergence in the last step of the proof.

Comment: @AddSup Can you please elaborate a bit on what you said so I can understand what you wrote with a bit more precision? Thank you

Comment: @AddSup Wouldnt your reasoning require that the density of $\langle M \rangle_t$ with respect to the lebesgue measure be bounded too in order to apply the dominated convergence theorem? And if thats the case, why is its density uniformly bounded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:** The assumption of absolute continuity is needed in the application of the dominated convergence theorem (DCT) at the end of the quoted proof.

**And the elaboration:** For simplicity, I'll let $n=1$. The argument doesn't depend on the value of $n$, but this conveniently normalizes $(\text{Leb}\times P)([0,1]\times\Omega)=1$. Also, $(\text{Leb}\times P)(H)=1$ where $H\triangleq\{(t,\omega):\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}X^{(m_k)}(t,\omega)=X(t,\omega)\}$. I note finally that in Karatzas and Shreve, $M$ is being assumed to be a square-integrable martingale (with continuous paths).

We're looking at 
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}E\int_0^1(X^{(m_k)}_t-X_t)^2d\langle M\rangle_t=:L.$$ 
Let $Y^k=\int_0^1(X^{(m_k)}_t-X_t)^2d\langle M\rangle_t$. To assert $L=E\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}Y^k$ by DCT, we need (i) $Y^k$ are dominated by an integrable random variable and (ii) $Y^k$ is convergent a.s.

The first part is covered by the uniform boundedness of $(X^{(m_k)}_t-X_t)^2$, say by $c\ge 0$, and the integrability of $\langle M\rangle_1$: $Y^k\le c\langle M\rangle_1$.

The second part is covered by another application of DCT, i.e., by the assertion that 
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}Y^k = \int_0^1\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(X^{(m_k)}_t-X_t)^2d\langle M\rangle_t=0\quad\text{a.s.}$$ 
To see this, recall first that $(X^{(m_k)}_t-X_t)^2$ is bounded. Next, let $S(\omega)=\{t:(t,\omega)\in H\}$. Then by Fubini's theorem, $\text{Leb}(S)=1$ a.s. ($\int_\Omega \text{Leb}(S)dP=(\text{Leb}\times P)(H)=1$. This is in fact not so much an application of Fubini's theorem as that of a lemma used in its proof.) *Since $\langle M\rangle$ is absolutely continuous a.s., $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(X^{(m_k)}_t-X_t)^2=0$ for $\langle M\rangle$-a.e. $t$, a.s.* This is where you need the a.s. absolute continuity of $\langle M\rangle$.

**Remark:** I don't think we need to invoke the RN derivative. A bounded RN derivative is a sufficient condition for an application of DCT, not a necessary condition.

---

**Addendum:** I'll add a few more words regarding the last paragraph.

We know two things here. One, $\text{Leb}(S)=1$ a.s. Two, the measure $\langle M\rangle$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure a.s.

Now let $\Omega'$ be a set of measure one on which both of these conditions hold. Then fix $\omega\in\Omega'$.

Then $\text{Leb}(S(\omega))=1$, which means $(t,\omega)\in H$ for Lebesgue-a.e. $t$. This in turn means, by the definition of $H$, that
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(X^{(m_k)}(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega))^2=0\quad
\text{for Lebesgue-a.e. }t.
$$
At the same time, $\omega\in\Omega'$ means that **the measure $\langle M\rangle(\omega)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, which in turn means that any event that has full measure under the Lebesgue measure must also have full measure under $\langle M\rangle(\omega)$**. (The definition of $\langle M\rangle(\omega)$ being absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure is that $\text{Leb}(A)=0\Rightarrow \langle M\rangle(\omega)(A)=0$. This implies that $\text{Leb}(A)=1\Leftrightarrow \text{Leb}(A^c)=0\Rightarrow \langle M\rangle(\omega)(A^c)=0\Leftrightarrow \langle M\rangle(\omega)(A)=\langle M\rangle_1(\omega)$. Apparently, I'm denoting the [Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) induced by $t\mapsto\langle M\rangle_t(\omega)$ again by $\langle M\rangle(\omega)$.) It follows that
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(X^{(m_k)}(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega))^2=0\quad
\text{for }\langle M\rangle(\omega)\text{-a.e. }t.
$$
Combined with the fact that the integrand $t\mapsto (X^{(m_k)}(t,\omega)-X(t,\omega))^2$ is bounded, then, by DCT we have
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}Y^k(\omega)=0.
$$
Since all this holds for all $\omega\in\Omega'$, we finally have the desired result that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}Y^k=0$ a.s.

Comment: I apologize if this is a stupid question but how does the almost sure absolute continuity of $\langle M \rangle$  imply $\lim_{k \to \infty}(X_t^{(m_k)}- X_t )^2=0$  for $\langle M \rangle$-a.e. $t$?

Comment: So here we use that since $\langle M \rangle$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the lebesgue measure and since $Leb(\lim_{k \to \infty} (X_t^{(m_k)}-X_t)^2 \neq 0) \implies \mu^{\langle M \rangle}(\lim_{k \to \infty} (X_t^{(m_k)}-X_t)^2) \neq 0)$ and hence $\lim_{k \to \infty} (X_t^{(m_k)}-X_t)^2 = 0, \langle M\rangle$-a.e $t$

Comment: @user3503589 Yes, you're right (provided you add the missing "$=0$" to both measures). I added more detail to my answer (see the addendum).

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explained answer .

Comment: @user3503589 You're welcome ;)