# $L^2$ convergence in the product measure implies convergence when the quadratic variation is absolutely continuous.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity, quadratic-variation

(This question is partially related [to another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105290/why-do-we-need-absolute-continuity-of-langle-m-rangle-t-omega-with-repect) on this forum.)

In Karatzas and Shreve, II edition, Chapter 3, we see in equation (2.2) the definition of the following measure on the product space $[0,\infty)\times\Omega$
$$
\mu_M(A) = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^{\infty}1_{A}(s,\omega)d\left<M\right>_s(\omega)\right] \quad (1)
$$

where $M$ is a continuous square integrable martingale and $A\in\mathcal{B}([0,\infty))\otimes\mathcal{F}$ is a measurable set of the product sigma algebra. So if $t\rightarrow\left<M\right>_t(\omega)$ is absolutely continuous (for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$) with respect to the **Lebesgue measure $\lambda$** we have that the measure in $(1)$ becomes
$$
\mu_M(A) = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^{\infty}1_{A}(s,\omega)f(s,\omega)ds\right] = \int_{\Omega}\left(\int_0^{\infty}1_{A}(s,\omega)f(s,\omega)ds\right)d\mathbb{P}\quad (2)
$$
with $f(s,\omega)\geq 0$. Later, in Lemma 2.4, it is stated and proved that if $X$ is a bounded, measurable and adapted process then there exists a sequence $\xi^{(n)}$ of simple processes such that
$$
\sup_{t>0}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t(\xi^{(n)}_s-X_s)^2ds\right] = 0\quad (3)
$$

I understand that this is $L^2$ convergence in the product measure $\lambda\otimes\mathbb{P}$ defined on the product $\sigma$ algebra

$$
\left(\lambda\otimes\mathbb{P}\right)(A\times B) = \lambda(A)\mathbb{P}[B]
$$

In fact the $(3)$ is equivalent to the integral with respect to   $\lambda\otimes\mathbb{P}$, i.e.

$$
\int_{\left[0,\infty\right)\times\Omega}g(s,\omega)d\left(\lambda\otimes\mathbb{P}\right) = \int_{\Omega}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}g(s,\omega)ds\right)d\mathbb{P}
$$

for a $\lambda\otimes\mathbb{P}$-measurable+integrable function $g$. Since $L^2$ convergence implies convergence in measure, we get that for all $\varepsilon>0$ it holds

$$
\int_{\Omega}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{\{\left|\xi^{(n)}_s(\omega)-X_s(\omega)\right|>\varepsilon\}}ds\right)d\mathbb{P}\rightarrow 0.
$$

The problem is: can I conclude now that

$$
\int_{\Omega}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{\{\left|\xi^{(n)}_s(\omega)-X_s(\omega)\right|>\varepsilon\}}f(s,\omega)ds\right)d\mathbb{P}\rightarrow 0.
$$

where $f$ is defined in $(2)$  ? Should $f$ be bounded, the implication would be obvious. But can I assume that $f$ is bounded? I think I am missing something important.

Comment: letting you know the link to the other question you tried linking broke

Comment: @PseudoLooped thanks, now is fixed.

Comment: if what is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue? Just above (2)

Comment: @G.Gare sorry, corrected accordingly.

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ: 1) yes, it is presented at Chapter 3, page 130, equation (2.2). 2) Sorry, $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Now the text is updated. The function $g$ is just any measurable function.

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ: the claimed equivalence should be a simple application of the Fubini Theorem.

Comment: How did you go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ concerning the function $f$ ?

Comment: @Hamdiken Because if $t\rightarrow G_t$ is an absolutely continuous function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) the corresponding  Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu_{G}$ is abs continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure (and vice versa). This means that $\mu_{G}(A)=\int_{A}d\mu_{G}=\int_{A}fd\lambda$ where $f$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @AlmostSureUser then I guess that using either the Dominated Convergence Theorem or Hölder, you can get the wanted convergence since in Wikipedia, it's stated that $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured out the solution. I added a new post with a more generic statement [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4569229/the-product-measure-when-one-of-the-measure-is-absolutely-continuous).